# Sum of two sum statements

Tags: sql-server-2008, sum

```
DECLARE @aracct VARCHAR(12)
    SET @aracct = '49920813'
DECLARE @item_no VARCHAR(12)
    SET @item_no = '2319'
SELECT tran_id, * FROM transactions
    WHERE account = @aracct AND item_no = @item_no
/*-----------Use if removing certain items from a check-----------*/
CREATE TABLE itemtable (items VARCHAR(6), account VARCHAR(12))
    INSERT INTO itemtable VALUES ('2299', @aracct)
    INSERT INTO itemtable VALUES ('2300', @aracct)
    --INSERT INTO @itemtable VALUES ('')
DECLARE @tran_id_pmt VARCHAR(6)
    SET @tran_id_pmt = '209413'

SELECT I1.result - I2.result AS 'final result'
FROM (SELECT SUM(amt_paid) AS result
      FROM transactions 
      WHERE account = @aracct AND item_no = @item_no) AS I1
JOIN (SELECT SUM(amt_paid) AS result
      FROM transactions 
      WHERE account = @aracct AND item_no = (SELECT items FROM itemtable)) AS I2
  ON (I1.account = I2.account)
```

Trying to get the sum 2 select statements and then sum those 2 statements, but I keep getting an error. Any ideas?

Comment: What error you get?  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Well right now it is saying that I1.account is not a correct column name...I tried doing transactions.account = itemtable.account, but it told me that it could not be bound

Comment: Where exactly you get that error? on the select? What is your db schema?

Answer (score 0):

You need include `account` on your subquery so you can use it on the `ON` condition

```
SELECT I1.result - I2.result AS 'final result'
FROM (SELECT account, SUM(amt_paid) AS result
             ^^^^^^^
      FROM transactions 
      WHERE account = @aracct AND item_no = @item_no
      GROUP BY account) AS I1
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
JOIN (SELECT account, SUM(amt_paid) AS result
      FROM transactions 
      WHERE account = @aracct AND item_no = (SELECT items FROM itemtable)
      GROUP BY account) AS I2
  ON (I1.account = I2.account)
         ^^^^^^^^
```

You could also solve it with a conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN item_no = @item_no THEN amt_paid
                                        ELSE 0
           END)
       -
       SUM(CASE WHEN item_no IN (SELECT items FROM itemtable) THEN amt_paid
                                                              ELSE 0
           END) AS 'final result'          
FROM Transactions
WHERE account = @aracct
```

Comment: Still the same error. (I1.account = I2.account) invalid column names

Comment: Doesnt make sense. Check again for some typos. Try run the inner select alone first and check for the column names.

Comment: With the second choice you gave me it is telling me that Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.